Woman moves into an apartment, awakes a vampire and falls in love with him
I don't have a whole lot to go on, but I recall watching a movie in my early childhood (i.e. early '90s) about a woman who moved into a new apartment and subsequently awoke a vampire who she later falls in love with. I recall the vampire being sort of clumsy, and her trying to adjust him to the modern world. 
I remember the architecture of the apartment looking like what you might find in San Fransisco. I definitely recall it having a small set of stairs leading up to the front door. I can't remember this for certain, but I believe the entrance to the vampire's tomb was through the fire place. 
Other details:

Live Action (color)
Most likely made in the U.S. or Canada
Could have been made during the 80's or early 90's
Comedy


Can we have more ID questions like this at least?   Clear, concise, including a list of attributes of the media. <3

Possibly Love Bites from 1993. From the Wiki recap:

Vampire Zachary Simms (Adam Ant) has just awakened in his coffin from a 100 year sleep in the crypt under Kendall's house and comes out through the secret door in her fireplace to face the brave, new world.

He soon befriends her. It also takes place in a house with a small set of stairs leading up to the front door. Here's a clip.
